# Please use POST request

Tags: javascript, html

While running the following script i am getting error "Please use POST request". I am just a beginner to html and javascript. Can any one help what is wrong here.

javascript

```
                 function submitform(){
        if (!document.getElementById('reschedule').onclick) {
            alert("reschedule")
        }
        if (!document.getElementById('home').onclick) {
            alert("home")
        }
        if (!document.getElementById('cancel').onclick) {
            alert("cancel")
        }
    }
```

and html is

```
   <html>
  <form name="myform" method="post,get" onsubmit="return submitform();">
<input type="submit" id="reschedule" value="reschedule" />
<input type="submit" id="home"  value="home" />
<input type="submit" id="cancel"  value="cancel" />
 </form>
```

Comment: The `method` attribute should be *either* "POST" or "GET"; not both.

Comment: You're binding the `onclick` event after the form is submitted. You don't need a click event anyway.

Answer (score 6):

```
<form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return submitform();">
```

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
method="post,get"
```

to this:

```
method="post"
```

In the `<form>` tag attributes

Comment: i tried that change and run it in jsfiddle.. but this time getting different error.         {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa2db66c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x9f520cc>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"}

Comment: you should add "django" in the question then. Sorry, I'm not a django expert.

Comment: You need to remove `type="submit"` from your `input` tags.

Comment: those are the 3 buttons on my html. i need 3 buttons like that

Comment: use `type="button"` instead

Comment: do i need to do any other changes.?

Comment: have a look at an HTML form tutorial. You need a `type="submit"` button to submit the form. You can also add buttons for different purposes, but they have to be of `type="button"`.